# Requesting a better approach to update the JS elements on fly

Tags: javascript

How do we obtain an argument from QueryString and then apply this to the JSON object.I have the following JS file, I would like to update the dashboard-metrics-target elements on fly on basis of querystring.. "target": "sumSeries(SERVER1.metric)", must be changed to SERVER2.metric on fly using the given template.

ex.. http://testdashabord.com/sla-network.incoming.bytes-2013.11.02/logs/test&server=192.168.1.103 must obtain my metrics for '192.168.1.103'

```
var graphite_url = "demo";  // enter your graphite url, e.g. http://your.graphite.com

var dashboards = 
[
  { "name": "Users",  // give your dashboard a name (required!)
    "refresh": 5000,  // each dashboard has its own refresh interval (in ms)
                ,
    "metrics":  // metrics is an array of charts on the dashboard
    [
      {
        "alias": "signups",  // display name for this metric
        "target": "sumSeries(SERVER1.metric)",  // enter your graphite barebone target expression here
        "description": "New signups to the website",  // enter your metric description here
        "summary": "sum",  // available options: [sum|min|max|avg|last|<function>]
        "summary_formatter": d3.format(",f"), // customize your summary format function. see d3 formatting docs for more options
      },
      {
        "alias": "signup breakdown",
        "target": "sumSeries(stats.*.event)",  // target can use any graphite-supported wildcards
        "description": "signup breakdown based on site location",
        "renderer": "area",  // use any rickshaw-supported renderer
        "unstack": true  // other parameters like unstack, interpolation, stroke are also available (see rickshaw documentation for more info)
        "colspan": 3  // the graph can span across 1,2 or 3 columns
      },

  ]
  }, ...
```

My Approach:
..1. Obtain the parameter from URL

```
var first = getUrlVars()["server"];

function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
```

..2. Update the elements of the array.

I would be thankful if a better approach is suggested.

Thanks

Comment: If `10.0.1.6/../ &server=server2` is supposed to be an example of a URL, it is a very bad and confusing example. It's better to say that you need to get the server from QueryString and then apply this to the JSON object. Why exactly do you not like your approach?

Comment: Updated the url and borrowed your text to formulate the question :), I am new to javascript, and the approach i have presented was first thing that struck my mind, however, I was hopeful that there are more systematic ways of achieving it, so i approached the community